# Django set model attribute to another model definition

Tags: django, django-models

I have a pair of models which I want to reference one another, but not as a foreign key. Ideally, I want this reference just to be an attribute the model. But the problem is that the second model wont have been created for the first to reference.

Example:

```
class model1(models.Model):
    ...
    relatedModel = model2


class model2(models.Model):
    ...
    relatedModel = model1
```

A similar thing happens when a foreign key is created using double quotes such as

```
field = models.foreignKey('someModel')
```

But I dont want this relationship to be a foreignkey...

I hope this makes sense,
thanks

Comment: Uhh... this is about as clear as mud. Why can't you just do it as above?

Comment: haha sorry Ignacio. I hope that makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class attributes don't always *need* to be set when the class is defined, certainly not in this case:

```
class model1(models.Model):
    ...

class model2(models.Model):
    ...
    relatedModel = model1

model1.relatedModel = model2
```